# Percentage column with Groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
Student   Exam    Month     
1         Maths    10      
1         Maths    10      
1         Maths    11      
1         Science  10      
1         Physics  10      
2         science  11
2         physics  11
2         Maths    12
```

I want this Output percentage of each exam by student , by Month

```
Student   Exam    Month    Pourcentage 
1         Maths    10      50%
1         Maths    11      100%
1         Science  10      25%
1         physics  10      25%
2         physics  11      50%
2         science  11      50%
2         Maths    12      100
```

i trying to use this code , But its doesn't give the right result

```
Count_exam= df.groupby('student','Exam')[Month].count()
Count_month= df.groupby('student')[Month].count()
df['Pourcentage] = Count_exam * 100 /Count_month
```

Comment: What does it give you?  Please include *all* details when requesting help.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can simply divide by `size` of each group:

```
df["Pct"] = 1/df.groupby(["Student", "Month"])["Exam"].transform("size")*100

print (df.groupby(["Student", "Exam", "Month"], as_index=False).agg("sum"))

   Student     Exam  Month    Pct
0        1    Maths     10   50.0
1        1    Maths     11  100.0
2        1  Physics     10   25.0
3        1  Science     10   25.0
4        2    Maths     12  100.0
5        2  physics     11   50.0
6        2  science     11   50.0
```